# making function with multiple variables to pass javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little snippet I want to make into a function. But I'm new to javascript. Obviously there is something wrong with the way I pass variables or the way I call them...

So in nutshell, this works: http://jsfiddle.net/kkvbz/
But this doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/PrtD4/

Problem is I need it as a function, so I've to make 1 version work.

Full snippet:

```
function cutandMakeslides (containerid,liperslide) {
//This is for footer slider, it rewrites 1 ul into several uls that contain 4 li max.
    // get the container, useful for later too...
    var container = $(containerid);

    // get all available UL and LI elements...
    var li_elements = container.find("> UL > LI").clone();

    // remove the current content so that we can rebuild it for the slider...
    container.find("> UL").remove();

    // build the slider container...
    var slide_container = $("<div />");

    // tricky part: looping through the LI's and building each of the slides...
    // first create some helpful variables...
    var li_elements_per_slide = liperslide;
    var li_counter = 0;

    // create the first slide, with a UL to hold the LI's...
    var current_li_div = $("<div />");
    current_li_div.append($("<ul />"));

    // loop through the LI's...
    li_elements.each(function(index, element){

        li_counter++;
        var current_li = $(element).clone();
        current_li_div.find("> UL").append(current_li);

        if (li_counter % li_elements_per_slide == 0)
        {
            // we've hit 4 in this list, so add the slide and make
            // a new one, using same code as before...
            container.append(current_li_div);
            current_li_div = $("<div />");
            current_li_div.append($("<ul />"));
        }

    });

    // we might have an uneven number of LI's, so we need to check for this...
    if (li_counter % li_elements_per_slide != 0)
        container.append(current_li_div);
} // end function cutandMakeslides


    //activate function above
    $(function() { cutandMakeslides(".fproductslides",3); });
```

Problematic parts:

```
function cutandMakeslides (containerid,liperslide) {
var container = $(containerid);
var li_elements_per_slide = liperslide;
}
$(function() { cutandMakeslides(".fproductslides",3); });
```

Comment: @danronmoon I updated OP with jsfiddle.

Comment: In the second fiddle, `container` is equal to a string: `"$('.fproductslides')"`.  Try just passing `$(containerClass)` to `container`.  JS won't evaluate your string as an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after extensive testing and moving the code to a fiddle, the problem seems to have resolved itself during moving it to the fiddle, so we believe there was a minor spelling or syntax error...however using a code comparison tool I was unable to find anything...

none of the problematic parts seemed to have an error:

```
function cutandMakeslides (containerid,liperslide) {
var container = $(containerid);
var li_elements_per_slide = liperslide;
}
$(function() { cutandMakeslides(".fproductslides",3); });
```

Here's a copy of the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrCord/PrtD4/2/)

Comment: Make sure you are using both different quotes exactly as I typed them.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object $('.fproductslides') has no method 'find'
It mentions this line: var li_elements = container.find("> UL > LI").clone();

Comment: That means you don't have that class on your page. try it with a class that works and you will see it working fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22921/discussion-between-drcord-and-sandro-dzneladze)

Comment: @SandroDzneladze - `Uncaught TypeError: Object $('.fproductslides') has no method 'find'` means that `$ !== jQuery`. Double-check that jQuery is loaded

Comment: @danronmoon positive jquery is loaded, other jquery scripts on the page work fine.

Answer (score 0):

From your 'problematic parts' section it appears you are trying to pass a class(".fproductslides" is a class, classes start with '.' and Id's start with '#') instead of an Id as your variable names lead me to believe you want to do...

Comment: I made an error naming variable. Html contains .fproductslides (class) not ID.